# Dart-Editor Hide / Remove Toolbars

Tags: dart, dart-editor

since dart really is built around this horrendous dart-editor, I would at least like to make it as emacs-like as possible.

I already use a gtk file to set everything to minimal, but I can't figure out how to hide the System-Bar (File, Edit, ...) and the Tool-Bar (Run, ...) as well as the Bottom-Bar showing position in text etc.

Is it possible to hide (all of) these toolbars?

Is there a shortcut for opening/closing the File-Browser so I don't have to have it open at all times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

DartEditor was built to have an easy start with Dart and it is quite powerful and tailored to Dart.
If you want more or other features you should consider using one of the other supported editors or IDEs.

See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/ for a list of editors or IDEs that have Dart support.

Sublime support was improved a lot recently and WebStorm 9 (preview version) also has quite good Dart support already.
I haven't tried others yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I use emacs for most work I have to do and would very much use it for dart was well.
What put me off was the interrupted workflow: Searching for simple spelling / syntax errors because I don't get any help but the pub-serve output. Any methods to improve that situation?

Comment: I have never really used Emacs and don't know what functionality the Dart plugin provides. As far as I understand the the ongoing work on the analyzer service should allow easier integration to other IDEs.